# Kotlin refresh imageview TornadoFX

Tags: java, android, kotlin, desktop-application, tornadofx

Im trying to refresh the image of an imageview on a button clink, but it doesnt seems like its working.
Here is my code:

```
class MasterView : View("Master View") {
    val controller: MyController by inject()
    val currentenemy = SimpleIntegerProperty(0)

    override val root = borderpane() {
        right = imageview(controller.monsters[currentenemy.value]) {
            setFitHeight(250.0)
            setFitWidth(175.0)
        }
        center = button("Change image") {
            action { currentenemy.value += 1 }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyController: Controller() {
    val monsters = FXCollections.observableArrayList("slime.png", "goblin.png", "mage.png", "knight.png", "boss.png")
}
```

I know that the values are changeing, but the imageview doesn't seem to care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the image view with a string value. There's nothing there to tell the image view to update when your `currentEnemy` property changes. For this, you need to give the image view an observable value that it can track.

For example:

```kotlin
right = imageview(currentEnemy.stringBinding { controller.monsters[it ?: 0] }) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand why it fixed it, but I tried to put the value in a SimpleStringProperty and pass that variable to the imageview, and now its updating on buttonclick.

```
val simplestring = SimpleStringProperty("slime.png")
...
imageview(observablepic)
center = button("Change image") {
    action { 
        currentenemy.value += 1 
        simplestring.value = controller.monsters[currentenemy.value]
    }
}
...
```

```
class MyController: Controller() {
    val monsters = FXCollections.observableArrayList("slime.png", "goblin.png", "mage.png", "knight.png", "boss.png")
}
```

Comment: This works because you are creating the image view with an observable string property. Your original was created with a plain string value.